# Aplicacion vb.net no se muestra al arrancarla desde programador de tareas

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en vb.net y quiero ponerla para que se ejecute automáticamente en un servidor al arrancar el sistema, por lo que estoy usando el programador de tareas de windows.

El problema es que si abro la aplicación manualmente (sin usar el programador de tareas) se muestra el formulario de la aplicación, pero si la ejecuta el programador de tareas o la fuerzo yo a ejecutarse desde el mismo, no se abre ningún formulario, aunque en el administrador de tareas aparece el proceso y la aplicación hace lo que debería..

¿Alguna idea de donde puede venir el problema?

**Edit**

He probado a crear un .bat que abra el programa, y que el programador de tareas abra ese .bat en vez del programa directamente, pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

**Edit 2**

Parece que al programar la tarea para que arranque aunque ningún usuario inicie sesion, se ejecuta como un servicio. Esa parece la razón por la que no se muestra ningún formulario.

Dejo la pregunta abierta por si a alguien se le ocurre algo nuevo pero parece no tener solucion.

Comment: ¿Con que usuario se ejecuta el schedule? tiene que ser con el mismo usuario que inicia sesión.

Comment: Se ejecuta con el usuario administrador del servidor, el mismo en el que estoy conectado. de todos modos, arranca cuando inicia el sistema aunque el usuario no se conecte

Comment: Lo más normal para este tipo de cosas es hacer un servicio de windows y que éste se comunique con una aplicación winforms (si quieres mostrar algún tipo de información sobre lo que hace el servicio, pararlo, etc).

Comment: Una pregunta.. porque tiene que estar en el programador de tareas? no basta con ponerla en inicio? ahi todas las apps se ejecutan como normales, no como servicios ni tareas. Todas las que vez en la barra de tareas van a parar ahi...

Comment: Se puede poner la aplicación de inicio, para que se ejecute aunque ningún usuario se conecte al servidor, la tarea se arranque al iniciar el sistema? si hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin el programador de tareas me vale.

Answer (score -2):

```
' Prueba a insertar-lo en el registro de windows con todas estas funciones podrás hacer lo que sea... 

' Para Su uso utiliza esta funcion asi, yo la pondria en el Form_Load
' AddStartup(Application.ExecutablePath, "NombreApp", RegistryStartup.StartupCurrentUser )





' Y Todo esto al principio del formulario principal

' Enumeracion de Tipos de Claves que se pueden Crear
    Public Enum RegistryKeyTypes
        RegSZ
        RegExpandSZ
        RegBinary
        RegDWord
        RegMultiSZ
    End Enum

' Enumeracion de Tipos de Registros de Inicio
Public Enum RegistryStartup
        StartupLocalMachine
        StartupCurrentUser
    End Enum

' Y Esta la agrega la App al inicio al inicio...
Public Function AddStartup(ByVal ApplicationPath As String, _
                               ByVal ApplicationName As String, _
                      Optional ByVal SetIn As RegistryStartup = RegistryStartup.StartupLocalMachine)
        On Error Resume Next

        Select Case SetIn
            Case RegistryStartup.StartupLocalMachine
                ' Esta solo funciona en XP
                WriteKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" & _
                         ApplicationName, ApplicationPath, RegistryKeyTypes.RegSZ)
            Case RegistryStartup.StartupCurrentUser
                WriteKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" & _
                         ApplicationName, ApplicationPath, RegistryKeyTypes.RegSZ)
        End Select

    End Function
' Función de Lectura de Registro
Public Function ReadKey(ByVal KeyRegPath As String) As Object
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim Reg As Object
        Reg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        ReadKey = Reg.RegRead(KeyRegPath)
        Reg = Nothing
    End Function

' Función de Escritura de Registro
Public Function WriteKey(ByVal KeyRegPath As String, _
                             ByVal ValueRegKey As Object, _
                             ByVal KeyType As RegistryKeyTypes) As Object  'Add New Key in Registry
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim RegistryReg As Object
        RegistryReg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        With RegistryReg
            Select Case KeyType
                Case RegistryKeyTypes.RegDWord
                    .RegWrite(KeyRegPath, ValueRegKey, "REG_DWORD")
                Case RegistryKeyTypes.RegBinary
                    .RegWrite(KeyRegPath, ValueRegKey, "REG_BINARY")
                Case RegistryKeyTypes.RegSZ
                    .RegWrite(KeyRegPath, ValueRegKey, "REG_SZ")
                Case RegistryKeyTypes.RegMultiSZ
                    .RegWrite(KeyRegPath, ValueRegKey, "REG_MULTI_SZ")
                Case RegistryKeyTypes.RegExpandSZ
                    .RegWrite(KeyRegPath, ValueRegKey, "REG_EXPAND_SZ")
            End Select
        End With
        RegistryReg = Nothing
    End Function

' Funcion de Comprobacion de Clave de Registro
Public Function ExistKey(ByVal KeyPath As String) As Boolean
        ' Comprobar si existe una Clave en el Registro
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim D As Object     ' Devuelve un Variant
        Dim ObjRegistro As Object

        ' Creamos un Objeto de Registro
        ObjRegistro = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        ' y accedemos a su valor
        D = ObjRegistro.RegRead(KeyPath)

        ' Si hay un error es que la Clave no existe
        If Err.Number = 0 Then ExistKey = True

        ' Descargamos el Objeto
        ObjRegistro = Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: Hola Pol, esta respuesta es de muy baja calidad y no tiene sentido alguno. Por favor lee [answer] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](/help/formatting) para más información y consejos para dar formato a tus publicaciones y que se vean mejor. Además, aunque este código está comentado, sería mejor que añadieses una descripción/comentario fuera del código, para que sea más fácil de leer y entender lo que estás compartiendo.